# svn commands hang on Mac

Tags: macos, svn

Need a help again. Whenever I try to run any svn command from command line on MacOS X 10.7, it hangs.

I have no clue why that's happening. svn commands work fine from within IntelliJ.

Can anyone help me find out what the problem is? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by moving to newer version:

```
...$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Aug 26 2011, 09:41:54
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use a proxy server to talk to the SVN repository, and you've got the proxy server configured in IntelliJ but not at the command line.  [Here's](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/http-proxy-sv/) a random blog post showing how to set up proxies for SVN command-line tools.

Comment: i checked, IntelliJ does not have any proxies configured for svn. will check the proxy creation.

Comment: Perhaps it's the converse: there's an (incorrect) proxy configured for the command-line tools, and none for IntelliJ.

Comment: well, i checked the inverse too, no proxies defined otherwise.